# Why my language server loses the JSON-RPC connection with the client in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, node.js, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'd like to create a language support extension for both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. In order to share most of the logic, I'd like to use the [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/). I ran [this simple VSCode LSP sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-sample) and it works fine. So my first goal was to download [the Visual Studio LSP sample](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/LanguageServerProtocol) and modify it to use the language server from the VS Code sample. I only modified the `ActivateAsync` function to use the Node-based language server like this:

```
public async Task<Connection> ActivateAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "node",
            Arguments = "server.js --stdio",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    if (process.Start())
    {
        return new Connection(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream, process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
    }

    return null;
}
```

According to the [Node-based LSP implementation's source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/blob/main/server/src/node/main.ts), it can communicate with the client by node-ipc, stdio, sockets, and pipes. The client is not Node-based so node-ipc is out of the question, and it seems that it uses only one pipe while Visual Studio requires 2, so I choose stdio.

I found some samples and extensions which use stdio to communicate with the server for example in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2022), in [the Rust extension](https://github.com/ZoeyR/rls-vs2017/blob/b097d6bfa456bb144ba2ee0c47e93dc648065dca/src/RustLanguageExtension/RustLanguageExtension.cs#L29), or in [the Python extension](https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/blob/main/Python/Product/PythonTools/PythonTools/LanguageServerClient/LanguageServer.cs). They do basically the same thing as I do, but when I try it and open a file in Visual Studio, I get this error:

> ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete.

**So my question is why do I get this error message, and how to solve it?**

Comment: It sound like a timeout issue.  Node-based LSP has a timer.  You are making an HTTP Request and should get back an HTTP Response.  Error indicates the connection is closing before the Response was received.  You could use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see when connection closes.  HTTP uses TCP for transport layer.  The TCP will show a [FIN] when the connection closes.  If server fails the error response would be 500 error for the Internal Server Error.  Even though the connection closes you may be able to capture the response status with the sniffer.

Comment: I don't really understand. I don't make HTTP requests. The client and the server are separate processes running locally, they exchange data in JSON format using the standard input and output.

Comment: Read following : http://www.simple-is-better.org/json-rpc/transport_http.html